# How to get quality bitmap when using "Imageview.draw(canvas)" in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am new to android, i am developing an app which is having 'draw' feature. for that i used 'draw' method in imageview to get what the imageview content. when i set the large bitmaps to imageview, the draw method returns low quality bitmap.

here is the code i used:

```
private Bitmap getImage() {
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageView.getWidth(), mImageView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(result);
mImageView.draw(c);
return result;}
```

**Before(original)::**
[image]

**After(using draw())::**
[image]
anyone have idea on this

please help me

Thanks

Comment: what is `Before(original)` image?

Comment: i mean original image before applying draw

Comment: so how come the image `After(using draw()` is larger than original? i mean for example you can see the whole house reflected in the lake (including the roof) while in original bitmap you can see only house's windows (with the roof cut off)

Comment: no its fine for image .problem is with quality if you observe roof you can see the lines on after image .

Comment: i mean on the original image, at the bootom, the roof of the house is cut off, while on the second image you can see the whole house, how is it possible?

Comment: Updated my images please check the quality and resolution of the images

Comment: check the physical dimensions of both images, it is quite normal that bigger (when it comes to width / height) image - the original one - will have much better quality, don't you think?

Comment: why can't you use your image as a resource?

Comment: @pskink ya of course, actually my intention is also same original one having quality but you can check second image 'After(using draw())' not having quality right.

Comment: @LamaTo ya i can use it but if i zoom the image the resultant image is different then the original one know. so here user can zoom the image and save it what they want.. i think you got my point.

Comment: so use `ImageView#getDrawable`: you will get the original `Drawable` that can be drawn later on

Comment: @pskink sorry i didn't get you correctly, how can we draw using drawable?

Comment: just study `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable` class documentation

Comment: i tried to use drawable.draw it is working fine when not applied zoom but if i applies zoom it returns original image not zoomed one

Comment: i thought you want "original" image (with no zoom) don't you? if you want zoomed you already got it with the code you posted

Comment: Mr.pskink you are correct but i am not getting quality(pix-elated image)  that is the reason i posted this question.

Comment: so i dont know what you want to achieve actually

Comment: my main moto is to draw image without losing quality. above image (before) is the image zoomed and crop in windows system and below image(after) is zoomed and cropped after applying draw() in android. please see the roof of the house  there is a noise in the image but not in original.

Comment: @syamvakkalanka did you find any solution ?